# IBM Watson TextToSpeech examples do not accept AUDIO_WAV as contentType

Tags: java, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Trying to run RecognizeUsingWebSocketsExample provided with IBM Watson SpeechToText Java SDK, but it's failing to create a valid RecognizeOptions object for the sample .wav file provided with the distribution:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When using PCM the audio rate should be specified.
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.Validator.isTrue(Validator.java:38)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.RecognizeOptions$Builder.contentType(RecognizeOptions.java:95)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.RecognizeUsingWebSocketsExample.main(RecognizeUsingWebSocketsExample.java:30)
```

It appears that the contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV) is being misinterpreted as RAW.  Here's the actual (unmodified from distro) code:

```
package com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.http.HttpMediaType;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.SpeechResults;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.websocket.BaseRecognizeCallback;

/**
 * Recognize using WebSockets a sample wav file and print the transcript into the console output.
 */
public class RecognizeUsingWebSocketsExample {
  private static CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

    SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
    service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");

    FileInputStream audio = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/speech_to_text/sample1.wav");

    RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
    .continuous(true)
    .interimResults(true)
    .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV)
    .build();

    service.recognizeUsingWebSocket(audio, options, new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onTranscription(SpeechResults speechResults) {
    System.out.println(speechResults);
    if (speechResults.isFinal())
      lock.countDown();
  }
});

lock.await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

}
}

I'm using 3.0.0-RC2 snapshot.  No problems running examples which do not use RecognizeOptions, like SpeechToTextExample.  Thx.

-rg

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, false alarm.  I recreated the example project from scratch and it compiled and ran without a hitch.  Must have been some weirdness with my Eclipse setup.